# How can I do google maps style scrolling on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make my own little map, I got something working so far in canvas, the only problem is that when I drag the map, it's limited to how far the mouse can move on the canvas, I need to be able to click and drag, and have the X,Y continue from where the mouse currently is, it is currently setting the X,Y on just mouse move, hope I made myself clear, here's a fiddle to see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/h7rYt/

And my code for handling the image movement on dragging:

```
can.onmousemove = function(e) { 
    if (map.moving) {
        console.log(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
        map.posX = e.pageX;
        map.posY = e.pageY;
    }
}

can.onmousedown = function() {
    map.moving = true;
}

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    map.moving = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the most recent mouse position and apply diffs from that each time. See http://jsfiddle.net/SMQZk/

```
can.onmousemove = function(e) { 
    if (map.moving) {
        console.log(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
        map.posX += e.pageX - map.lastX;
        map.posY += e.pageY - map.lastY;
        map.lastX = e.pageX;
        map.lastY = e.pageY;
    }
}

can.onmousedown = function(e) {
    map.lastX = e.pageX;
    map.lastY = e.pageY;
    map.moving = true;
}
```